# init and initWithNibName are not called but viewDidLoad is called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

init and initWithNibName are not called at all but viewDidLoad is called.
Any thought?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe `initWithCoder:` is called. Is your controller instanciated via Nib ?

Comment: Or just `init`. But nibs call `initWithCoder`, so that's probably it in this case.

Answer (score -1):

You are loading the controller from a nib, this surely cannot call `initWithNibName:...` as you hopefully will understand. Just put all the code which would have gone there in `viewDidLoad` or stick with the solution mentioned by Vince

Comment: condescending and inaccurate. if you create a VC programmatically using an NIB, initWithNibName will be called if you call init during creation.